# @ConfigurationProperties: Default value in bound class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a config class `FooConfig`, in which i have a bound class 'Foo'.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
public class FooConfig {

  @Value("${foo.default.iterations}")
  private Integer iterations;

  private Foo foo;

  // getter / setter

}
```

In my class `Foo` I want the iterations-variable set with an existing default configuration-value, when not explicitly set in the properties-file.

```
public class Foo {

  private String name;

  @Value("${foo.default.iterations}")
  private Integer iterations;

  // getter / setter

}
```

My properties file

```
foo.default.iterations=999

# if this is set this config is bound (wins) in FooConfig-class as expected
# foo.iterations=111

foo.foo.name=foo
```

Setting a default value in `FooConfig` works, but not in my bound class `Foo`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 91):

You shouldn't mix `@Value` and `@ConfigurationProperties` in the same class. If you want to have default values in a `@ConfigurationProperties`-annotated class, you can configure the fields with a default value:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
public class FooConfig {

    private Integer iterations = 999;

    // getter / setter

}
```

This change brings with it the added benefit of including the default value in the metadata that's generated by `spring-boot-configuration-processor`. The metadata is used by your IDE to provide auto-completion when you're editing `application.properties` and `application.yaml` files.

Lastly, and not directly related to your problem, a `@ConfigurationProperties`-annotated class should not be annotated with `@Configuration`. An `@Configuration`-annotated class is used to configure beans via `@Bean` methods. Your `FooConfig` class should either be annotated with `@Component` or you should use `@EnableConfigurationProperties(FooConfig.class)` on the `@Configuration` class that wants to use `FooConfig`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out several mistakes. But my initial problem still remains: My aim is not to hard-code the default-values, but retrieve them from the a properties-file if not set.

Comment: That's a different question to the one that I thought you had asked. To do that, I'd use an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to load a separate file that contains the defaults into a new `PropertySource` with very low precedence so that the values are overridden by most or even all other property sources. You'd use the same keys (for example `foo.iterations`) when configuring both the defaults and any overrides.

Comment: And thanks again for leading me the way. But in this case I think its too much overhead. Would be nice if Spring would come up with some kind of `@DefaultValue` annotation one day.

Comment: How would an annotation help with your goal of not hard-coding the default values? As I already mentioned, you can include a default value in your code by initialising the field with the desired default value. This has the added benefit of being picked up by Spring Boot's configuration processor at compile time so that the defaults are then included in the metadata that your IDE uses when offering auto-completion.

Answer (score 0):

Put default values in the `resources/application.yml`
Then you can override them by supplying an external `application.yml` (outside packaged jar) file.

Comment: One issue with this approach is that it's all or nothing: if you have more than one value with a default property, you can either override them all or none, but not just some.