# @DefaultValue not working with @ConstructorBinding for Spring boot 2.4.2

Tags: spring-boot

Here is an example of my problem. when no value is supplied to default-name in yml file. `@DefaultValue` should step in and fill with `"Name"`. However, is not how it behaves. An empty string is assigned to defaultName

**application.yml:**

```
account:

  default-name:
```

**class:**

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "account")
public class Account {

  private final String defaultName;

  public Account(@DefaultValue("Name") String defaultName) {
    this.defaultName = defaultName;
  }
  ..
  ..

}
```

Comment: Hi & Welcome to [so], *but* you *assign* an empty string (in your application.yml;)! (trying to say, that an "empty string" is not (exactly) the same as "no value")

Comment: pleasy "try": deleting/commenting the "key" completely from the yml... also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51611069/592355) is very useful (from pre-@DefaultValue times ;)